# index2.php in root causing 404 error

Tags: 404-error

I put up a quick splash page with `index.php` and added a link in that splash page to index2.php and when I go to `index2.php`, I get a *"page not found"* error. Getting rid of the splash is not an option right now. Is there anything I can do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to just use a index.html file and use

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5; URL=http://example.com/wp-content/themes/your_theme/index.php">`

in your `<head>` section.

Let's see if the easy stuff works.

*edit:* to be on the save side, always display a link to the index.php file with some descriptive text like "if your browser doesn't redirect you automatically, please click *here*"

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify: So I should try changing index.php (which is the splash page now) to index.html with the addition of the head content? Or do you mean change index2.php to index.html?

Comment: Also, to clarify further, it looks like index2.php is showing everything but the main section. That is the header, sidebar, and footer. But no 'main' section. I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Afaik the index.html get's catched first, so yes, your index.php. The index2.php would get renamed to index.php and serve it's normal purpose as your theme's index file. Give it a try. I'm not exactly sure if it will work.

Comment: Oh, and no, i don't know what the "main" section is...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a custom page and name it home.php to load it first and link it where you want.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy